# List of Composables /Unit

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a list of `Composables` i want to display in an `HorizontalPager`,these composables functions are composable components (e.g  `Button`, `InputTextfield`, `Box`, `Column` etc).

```
@Composable
fun FirstScreen(){
 returns Column()
}

@Composable
fun SecondScreen(){
 returns Box()
}

val screens = ArrayList<Unit>()
        screens.add(FirstScreen())
        screens.add(SecondScreen())

val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        pageCount = items.size,
        initialOffscreenLimit = 2,
        infiniteLoop = false,
        initialPage = 0,
    )
```

I place my `HorizontalPager` in a `Scaffold` and load the composable unit to display

```
  Scaffold(
            floatingActionButton = floatingActionButton,
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    title = title,
                    backgroundColor = topAppBarBackgroundColor,
                    showBackIcon,
                    onBackPressed
                )
            },
            content = { 
              HorizontalPager(state = pagerState, count = items.size,modifier = 
                 Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { page ->
                    items[page]
             }
              }
        )
```

Im able to see the composable function screen displayed in the horizontal pager, but the actions on the screens are disabled or not responding, ie i cant onClick a button or even gain focus for an input fields.Kindly advice what i've missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Composable
fun FirstScreen(){
   Column()
}

@Composable
fun SecondScreen(){
   Box()
}


@Composable
fun PagerScreen(){

val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton = floatingActionButton,
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = title,
                backgroundColor = topAppBarBackgroundColor,
                showBackIcon,
                onBackPressed
            )
        },
        content = {
            HorizontalPager(state = pagerState, count = items.size,modifier =
            Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { page ->
                when(page){
                    0-> FirstScreen()
                    1-> SecondScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    )}
```

Please try this. Hope it will help

Comment: i think there should be a better way to host and manage several composable screens in one composable  instead of using a viewpager @vera Iureva